# Image not rendering after upgrading react native version

Tags: android, react-native

I created a new project in react-native **0.61.5**. My old project was runnning on **0.49.5**.

My images in my view are no longer rendering, this is what I'm getting:

[image: image of android emulator with no picture rendered where there should be a picture]

After porting all my code from my old project to my new project and installing the necessary dependencies everything worked as expected with the exception of the rendering of the image.  The image I'm using comes from a URI (**URI still working in browser**), and I'm fetching a new image every time an event is executing (swiping right)

Here is the code in question:

```js
  renderCard = (card, index) => {
    // https://source.unsplash.com/featured/?{dog}
    return (
      <View style={styles.card}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>card: {card} index: {index}</Text>
        <Image style={{width: 400, height: 400}} source={{uri: 'https://source.unsplash.com/400x400/?dog/' + index}}/>
      </View>
    )
  };
```

Here is my render method that makes the call to the renderCard method above:

```js
  render () {
    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={[styles.swiper]}>
        <Swiper
          ref={swiper => {
            this.swiper = swiper
          }}
          onSwiped={() => this.onSwiped('general')}
          onSwipedLeft={() => this.onSwiped('left')}
          onSwipedRight={() => this.onSwiped('right')}
          onSwipedTop={() => this.onSwiped('top')}
          onSwipedBottom={() => this.onSwiped('bottom')}
          onTapCard={this.swipeLeft}
          cards={this.state.cards}
          cardIndex={this.state.cardIndex}
          cardVerticalMargin     = {100}
          renderCard={this.renderCard}
          onSwipedAll={this.onSwipedAllCards}
          useViewOverflow    = {false}
          stackSize={3}
          stackSeparation={15}

          overlayLabels={{
            bottom: {
              title: 'BLEAH',
              style: {
                label: {
                  backgroundColor: 'black',
                  borderColor: 'black',
                  color: 'white',
                  borderWidth: 1
                },
                wrapper: {
                  flexDirection: 'column',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center'
                }
              }
            },
            left: {
              title: 'NOPEE',
              style: {
                label: {
                  backgroundColor: 'black',
                  borderColor: 'black',
                  color: 'white',
                  borderWidth: 1
                },
                wrapper: {
                  flexDirection: 'column',
                  alignItems: 'flex-end',
                  justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                  marginTop: 30,
                  marginLeft: -30
                }
              }
            },
            right: {
              title: 'LIKE',
              style: {
                label: {
                  backgroundColor: 'black',
                  borderColor: 'black',
                  color: 'white',
                  borderWidth: 1
                },
                wrapper: {
                  flexDirection: 'column',
                  alignItems: 'flex-start',
                  justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                  marginTop: 30,
                  marginLeft: 30
                }
              }
            },
            top: {
              title: 'SUPER LIKE',
              style: {
                label: {
                  backgroundColor: 'black',
                  borderColor: 'black',
                  color: 'white',
                  borderWidth: 1
                },
                wrapper: {
                  flexDirection: 'column',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center'
                }
              }
            }
          }}
          animateOverlayLabelsOpacity
          animateCardOpacity
          swipeBackCard
        >


        </Swiper>
        </View>
        <View style={[styles.rateBoxes]}>
          <Slider
            style={{width: 200, height: 40}}
            minimumValue={5}
            maximumValue={10}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

## Update 1

I modified my code to try and render an image outside the Swiper method as such:

```js
render () {
    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.card}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>card:</Text>
        <Image style={{width: 400, height: 400}} source={{uri: 'https://source.unsplash.com/400x400/?dog/' + "1"}}/>
      </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Interestingly enough, **no image was rendered**, This was what I got:
[image: image of android emulator with no picture rendered where there should be a picture]

And here is my **stylesheet**:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#4FD0E9'
  },
  swiper:{
    flex:1,
  },
  rateBoxes:{
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 10
  },
  card: {
    flex: 1,
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#E8E8E8',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
  text: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  done: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 30,
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  }
})
```

## Update 2

The package I am using for swiper is called react-native-deck-swiper.
Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "DogTinder",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-deck-swiper": "^1.6.7",
    "react-native-view-overflow": "0.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.57.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you render the Image outside <Swiper/>? And share your package name u used for swipes

Comment: Interestingly enough.  When I try to render the image outside the <Swiper/> (but within <View style={styles.container}>) it still dosen't work. The package I am using for swiper is called react-native-deck-swiper

Comment: I've added the code I tried to my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your emulator is not connected to the internet:
[image: Screenshot of emulator with a internet not conected icon circled]

To double check your emulator is connected to the internet, open a browser and try to go to Google.

If **no webpage is diplayed** try the following to solve your issue:

1. On your emulator go to settings -> turn off wifi and turn off data and turn on again and it will fix in some cases
2. Completely close out of your emulator and re-start it.

Comment: The internet for my emulator is indeed not working. I can't load any webpages on the browser. I tries turning the data and wifi on and off again but that didn't work... I'm now trying to restart my emulator.

Comment: Closing out of my emulator and re-opening it did the trick! Thanks! Can you update your answer with the steps I took to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the code with

```
renderCard = (card, index) => {
  const imageUri = 'https://source.unsplash.com/400x400/?dog/' + index;
  return (
    <View style={styles.card}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>card: {card} index: {index}</Text>
      <Image style={{width: 400, height: 400}} source={{uri: imageUri }}/>
    </View>
  )
};
```